# WPF Display variable in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, variables

I wrote a program which displays the color and the depth stream of a kinect sensor. In the depth image it's possible for the user to select two points and the program displays the coordinates of the points. Now I want to improve my program. So I added a new window called Disatance.xaml. This window is opened when the user checks a Check-box. In this window I want to show the coordinates, rather then in the MainWindow. So I need to pass the integer variables of the x- and y-Coordinates. My problem now is that I'm really new to C# and I don't know a way to pass integers from one window to an other window. I really how somebody can help me.
The main code is executed in the main window. In that I open the second window, by clicking on a button. My code looks like this:

```
    private void CmdDistance_Click(object senderr, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Distance distance = new Distance();
            distance.Show();
    }
```

The coordinates are currently calculatet and displayed by my function void Mouse_ClickTest:

```
    private void Mouse_ClickTest(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChkDistance.IsChecked == true)
        {
            System.Windows.Point myMousePosition = e.GetPosition(DepthImage);

            double xpixel = myMousePosition.X;
            double ypixel = myMousePosition.Y;
            int xpos = (int)xpixel;
            int ypos = (int)ypixel;
            if ((xpos > 0 || ypos > 0) && (xpos <= 640 || ypos <= 480))
            {
                int depthWidth = mySensor.DepthStream.FrameWidth;
                int depthIndex = xpos + (ypos * depthWidth);
                if (depthIndex < 307840)
                {
                    SkeletonPoint mySkeletonArray = this.mySkeletonArray[depthIndex];
                    float zpos = mySkeletonArray.Z;
                    zpos = zpos * 1000;
                    int z = (int)zpos;
                    float xp = mySkeletonArray.X;
                    xp = xp * 1000;
                    int x = (int)xp;
                    float yp = mySkeletonArray.Y;
                    yp = yp * 1000;
                    int y = (int)yp;
                    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                    {
                        if (i == false)
                        {
                            TxtCoordX.Text = string.Format("X: {0}", x);
                            TxtCoordY.Text = string.Format("Y: {0}", y);
                            TxtCoordZ.Text = string.Format("Z: {0}", z);
                            i = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TxtCoordX2.Text = string.Format("X: {0}", x);
                            TxtCoordY2.Text = string.Format("Y: {0}", y);
                            TxtCoordZ2.Text = string.Format("Z: {0}", z);
                            i = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to pass the integer variable x, y and z to the window Distance

Comment: Do you have the two windows? How are these two windows created? is one of them a dialog which is opened from the other? can you show code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your `Distance` class higher in scope in your `MainWindow` class. The way you have it right now, it's created and goes out of scope once the Click handler completes execution.
2. The quickest and dirtiest way to do what you're asking is to create a method in the code-behind of your Distance form. It could be something like:

   public void SetCoordinates(float x, float y, float z)
   {
      //Set properties here
   }

Then you can make TextBlocks or TextBoxes to those properties.

1. You can also initialize the x,y,z to a value by passing them in the constructor:

Instead of:

```
new Distance();
```

Do:

```
new Distance(float x, float y, float z);
```

Then you can make TextBlocks or TextBoxes to those properties.